# Getting Value Error when calculating time diffrences from a reference time in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given a `df`

```
4,2019-01-15 07:00:00
0,2019-01-15 07:00:05
3,2019-01-15 07:00:10
3,2019-01-15 07:00:15
3,2019-01-15 07:00:20
1,2019-01-16 10:00:00
3,2019-01-16 10:00:05
2,2019-01-16 10:00:10
4,2019-01-16 10:00:15
0,2019-01-16 10:00:20
```

I would like to calculate the time diffrence between the first row and the subsequent rows under the column `time` and express the result in the unit of seconds.

```
df['elapse_second']=pd.Timedelta(df['time'] - df.loc[0,'time']).seconds / 3600.0
```

However the compiler return an error

```
ValueError: Value must be Timedelta, string, integer, float, timedelta or convertible, not Series
```

The code to reproduce the above error is

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

np.random.seed(0)
data_time=['2019-01-15 7:00:00','2019-01-16 7:00:00']
lapse=5 # unit in second
alist=[pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5,size=(5)),columns=['data']) for _ in range (2)]
all_df=[]
for disdf,ndata_time in zip(alist,data_time):
  disdf['time']=pd.date_range(start=ndata_time, periods=len(disdf), freq='5S')
  all_df.append(disdf)

df=pd.concat(all_df).reset_index(drop=True)

# t1 = pd.to_datetime('2019-01-15 7:00:00')
t1=df.loc[0,'time']
df['elapse_second']=pd.Timedelta(df['time'] - df.loc[0,'time']).seconds / 3600.0
```

Expected output

```
4,2019-01-15 07:00:00,0
0,2019-01-15 07:00:05,5
3,2019-01-15 07:00:10,10
3,2019-01-15 07:00:15,15
3,2019-01-15 07:00:20,20
1,2019-01-16 10:00:00,86400
3,2019-01-16 10:00:05,86405
2,2019-01-16 10:00:10,86410
4,2019-01-16 10:00:15,86415
0,2019-01-16 10:00:20,86420
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the dtype to `'timedelta64[s]'` since you want the difference in seconds.

Replace

```
df['elapse_second']=pd.Timedelta(df['time'] - df.loc[0,'time']).seconds / 3600.0
```

with

```
df['elapse_second']=(df['time'] - df.loc[0,'time']).astype('timedelta64[s]')
```

and your code will produce the expected outcome.

Output:

```
   data                time  elapse_second
0     4 2019-01-15 07:00:00            0.0
1     0 2019-01-15 07:00:05            5.0
2     3 2019-01-15 07:00:10           10.0
3     3 2019-01-15 07:00:15           15.0
4     3 2019-01-15 07:00:20           20.0
5     1 2019-01-16 07:00:00        86400.0
6     3 2019-01-16 07:00:05        86405.0
7     2 2019-01-16 07:00:10        86410.0
8     4 2019-01-16 07:00:15        86415.0
9     0 2019-01-16 07:00:20        86420.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your `time` column is already a `datetime`, you can simply subtract the `1st row` using [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and extract the `seconds` from thr result using [`Series.dt.seconds`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.seconds.html):

```
In [475]: df['difference_in_seconds'] = (df['time'] - df.loc[0, 'time']).dt.seconds

In [476]: df
Out[476]: 
   data                time  difference_in_seconds
0     4 2019-01-15 07:00:00                      0
1     0 2019-01-15 07:00:05                      5
2     3 2019-01-15 07:00:10                     10
3     3 2019-01-15 07:00:15                     15
4     3 2019-01-15 07:00:20                     20
5     1 2019-01-16 10:00:00                  10800
6     3 2019-01-16 10:00:05                  10805
7     2 2019-01-16 10:00:10                  10810
8     4 2019-01-16 10:00:15                  10815
9     0 2019-01-16 10:00:20                  10820
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sorry for not so clear, but the shift and NAN is not required here. It is sufficient to have on `t1=df.loc[0,'time']
df['elapse_second']=(df['time']-t1).dt.seconds`

Comment: Oh. You wanted the time diff of `1st row` with all other rows. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Yes, u r correct, sorry make thing vague

Comment: @rpb Please check my updated answer.

Comment: mmmm, I think there is something wrong, if in data_time I use '2019-01-16 7:00:00' instead of '2019-01-16 10:00:00', elapse at row 5-9 should be 86400,86405,